# Font size of plot title in rmarkdown after using facet_multiple

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, r-markdown

I'm using facet_multiple to produce 10 pages of plots in 2x2 style. While the plots themselves look good, the font size of the plot title is quite small. Either facet_multiple or when I go to knit the document is overriding the font size within the graph.

This is the graph:

```
P <- Data_Backs %>% 
group_by(Player.Name, Period,Day_Week) %>% 
summarise(mean_M_Min=mean(M_Min)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Period,y=mean_M_Min,colour=Day_Week, group=Day_Week)) + 
geom_line(size=2)+
geom_hline(yintercept = 120, show.legend = T)+
ylim(0,200)+
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5)))+
theme(legend.text=element_text(size=30),
    plot.title = element_text(size=50))
```

And this:

````
```{r cars, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE,  fig.height = 30, 
fig.width = 30, fig.align = "center", }
facet_multiple(plot = P, facets = "Player.Name", ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
````

Which produces a number of the following grids

[image]

The plot title is barely legible due to font size

Comment: What do you mean by 'plot title'? The overall title at the top of the series of plots? You don't seem to specify one. If you mean the titles at the top of each individual facet, those are controlled by `theme(strip.text = element_text())`.

Comment: @Marius Yes, it was title at the top of each individual facet, apologies for any confusion. Thank you for the solution

Comment: @NColl: Where did `facet_multiple` function come from?

Comment: @Tung It's part of the `ggplus` package

Comment: If you make the plot 30 inches, it makes sense that the text is relatively small

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score -1):

`fig.height` and `fig.width` define plot size in **inches**. I think you need to make them smaller. Start with 6x6 and manually correct it until success.

Answer (score -1):

Try `out.width = "100%"` rather than `fig.height = 30, fig.width = 30`.